# Developer Account Registration

Tags: account, developer, setup

I have registered a new developer account. So i got an email asking me to activate. When I click the "Verify Account" in the email, network was cut for some reason. I click the "Verify Account" again and i am now brought to the login page. The first time setup where you would set your initial password and security question is no longer presented.

Since i have not set the first time password, I tried to reset my password. And so I got another email telling me that salesforce has finished resetting my password, with link for me to finish my part. But when I clicked the link, I am being asked for the City where I as born, which I never set, which obviously wouldn't accept any guess i could make.

What to do to now EXCEPT registering for another account?